# Read weblogic.xml values overwritten by deployment plan?

Tags: deployment, weblogic, weblogic12c

I have a web application with `<security-role-assignment>` nodes in `weblogic.xml`
Eg:

```
<security-role-assignment>
    <role-name>Application Role 1</role-name>
    <principal-name>Active Directory Group Principal</principal-name>
</security-role-assignment>
```

During the deployment in WebLogic the `principal-name` are overwritten with a deployment plan to set the correct group principal name (this works).

I now have to access that role-name <-> principal-name mapping programatically from within the web application.

Reading the `weblogic.xml` this way does not work, that results in the original (unmodified by the deployment plan) XML and values:

`request.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/weblogic.xml")`

**Question**

*How can I access entries in `weblogic.xml` which are overwritten by a deployment plan?*

Comment: When WebLogic deploys your application with a deployment plan, WebLogic merges the deployment descriptors with the plan and writes the result in the server's tmp directory. The best way to get configuration informations is JMX and configuration mbeans published by WebLogic. Have a look to the [MBean Reference Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57014_01/wls/WLMBR/core/index.html) to find informations you need. But, i'm not sure that these security informations will be available.

Comment: The merged result (weblogic.xml) is not available in the tmp directory under the server (I searched through all files). Any idea where the merged result resides?

Comment: Are you deploying your application with Eclipse ?

Comment: No, IntelliJ (but I guess that is similar to Eclipse). Does that make a difference?

Comment: These tmp files can be handled directly by Eclipse or IntelliJ. Take a look on their side. Anyway, if you deploy your application in a test, qa or production env, merge files will be found under server's tmp directory. But once again i do not think this is a good approach.

Comment: I now deployed the EAR + plan through the WebLogic console and I don't see the merged weblogic.xml files in the tmp dir. Only the originals. Am I doing something wrong? 

It seems that the merged weblogic.xml files should be available somewhere, right?